# How can I formally say "I'm getting into work, we talk later"?

Tags: formal-language

I thought about "I'm going to enter my work now", but I'm both not sure if it formal or even correct.

Context: in a conversation in WhatsApp, where I will stop the conversation because I'm entering my work/workplace.

Comment: Do you mean "formal written style" or "Polite spoken style" or something else?

Comment: @james spoken, or via WhatsApp

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp is not a forum for "formal English" (such as you might find in a business letter), so what you want is "Polite spoken English". There is nothing much impolite about what you said. You could leave it unchanged or make minor tweaks.

> I'm getting to work now. We'll talk later.

I've changed "into" to "to", because there is an idiom "get into" that means "become enthusiastic about".  In context there is no real ambiguity, but using "to" avoids it completely. I've changed the tense in the final phrase. Again, the meaning was already clear, but a future "will" works better with the phrase "later".

Answer (score 0):

I often use the line - I reached my office(workplace). will get back to you some other time. 
 -(hoping you want to convey someone you are entering your office building and want to convey in a polite way)